# Ansible access JSON object with dynamic key and special character

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible script that performs API call and stores the JSON result in a variable. The JSON result from the API call is in the following format:

```
{
        "result": {
          "Object::18": {
            "message": "object message"
          },
          message: "hello"
        }
}
```

In this case the key `Object::18` is dynamically generated from the ID given as argument in the Ansible script:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yaml --extra-var='id=18'
```

How do I get the JSON value for key `result.Object::{{id}}.message` in this case? Please find below a sample Ansible script:

```
- name: Get API object
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    object_id: '{{ id }}'

    # Sample JSON result returned by the API call
    # Object::<id> (the key "Object::<id>" depends on the ID given as argument for the ansible script)
    # For example, if run using --extra-vars "id=18", it will be Object::18. If id=19 then Object::19
    sample_json_result:
      {
        "result": {
          "Object::18": {
            "message": "object message"
          },
          message: "hello"
        }
      }
  tasks:
  - debug:
      # How to get result.Object::<id>.message???
      # For example 1: --extra-vars "id=18", result.Object::18.message
      # Example 2: --extra-vars "id=19", result.Object::19.message
      msg: '{{ sample_json_result.result }}'

      # The following does NOT work
      #msg: '{{ sample_json_result.result.Object\:\:{{id}}.message }}'
```

Thank you and please let me know if you have any further questions.

*EDIT:*

For those who are interested, solution as suggested by Zeitounator

```
- name: Get API object
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    object_id: '{{ id }}'

    # Sample JSON result returned by the API call
    # Object::<id> (the key "Object::<id>" depends on the ID given as argument for the ansible script)
    # For example, if run using --extra-vars "id=18", it will be Object::18. If id=19 then Object::19
    sample_json_result:
      {
        "result": {
          "Object::18": {
            "message": "object message"
          },
          message: "hello"
        }
      }
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ sample_json_result.result["Object::" ~ id].message }}'
```

Comment: => `{{ result['Object::' ~ id].message }}`. Good read: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and reference! For those who are interested, to get the string "object message" in this case, use the following: `'{{ sample_json_result.result["Object::" ~ id].message }}'`